# Confusion with Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, integration, semiclassical

The Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization condition reads $$\oint p(x)dx=(n+1/2)h,$$
where $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ and in general, the RHS is nonzero. Now,
$$\oint p(x)dx=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}p(x)dx+\int_{x_2}^{x_1}p(x)dx=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}p(x)dx-\int_{x_1}^{x_2}p(x)dx=0.$$
How can RHS be anything other than zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed path is  in a two-dimensional space with coordinates $(p,x)$. You can't specify the path by just giving $x_1$, $x_2$ limits.

For example in a harmonic oscillator you can have
$$
x(t)= \cos \omega t\\
p(t)= -\sin \omega t.
$$

Comment: moreover the sign of $p$ will change around the loop…

Answer (score 1):

No, the phase integral $\oint p\ dx$ is usually positive.
Consider this closed path in phase space.

[image]

A rectangle in the upper red half (with $dx$ and $p$ both positive)
makes a positive contribution to the integral.
And a rectangle in the lower green half (with $dx$ and $p$ both negative)
also makes a positive contribution to the integral.